# Automating pl\sql functions

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I want to automate the registrations system so that it automatically registers students. Then I want a procedure to automate the grading system. I have included the code that I am written to make most of this assignment work which it does but unsure how to incorporate PL\SQL automated functions for the registrations system, and the grading system. So any help or ideas I would greatly appreciated please.

```
set Linesize 250
set pagesize 150

drop table student;
drop table faculty;
drop table Course;
drop table Section;
drop table location;
DROP TABLE courseInstructor;
DROP TABLE Registration;
DROP TABLE grade;

create table student( 
studentid   number(10),
Lastname    varchar2(20),
Firstname   Varchar2(20),
MI              Char(1),
address             Varchar2(20),
city         Varchar2(20),
state        Char(2),
zip      Varchar2(10),
HomePhone        Varchar2(10),
Workphone        Varchar2(10),
DOB      Date,
Pin VARCHAR2(10),
Status  Char(1));

ALTER TABLE Student 
Add Constraint Student_StudentID_pk Primary Key (studentID);

Insert into student values (1,'xxxxxxxx','xxxxxxxxxx','x','xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx','Columbus','oh','44159','xxx-xxx-xxxx','xxx-xxx-xxxx','06-Mar-1957','1211','c');    

create table faculty(
FacultyID   Number(10),
FirstName   Varchar2(20),
Lastname    Varchar2(20),
MI  Char(1),
workphone   Varchar2(10),
CellPhone   Varchar2(10),
Rank    Varchar2(20),
Experience  Varchar2(10),
Status  Char(1));

ALTER TABLE Faculty
ADD Constraint Faculty_facultyId_PK PRIMARY KEY (FacultyID);

insert into faculty values (1,'xxx','xxxxxxxxxxxx','xxx-xxx-xxxx','xxx-xxx-xxxx','professor','20','f');

create table Course(
CourseId        number(10),
CourseNumber    Varchar2(20),
CourseName      Varchar(20),
Description     Varchar(20),
CreditHours     Number(4),
Status      Char(1));

ALTER TABLE Course
ADD Constraint Course_CourseID_pk PRIMARY KEY(CourseID);

insert into course values (1,'cit 100','computer concepts','introduction to PCs','3.0','o');
insert into course values (2,'cit 101','Database Program','Database   Programming','4.0','o');
insert into course values (3,'Math 101','Algebra I','Algebra I Concepts','5.0','o');
insert into course values (4,'cit 102a','Pc applications','Aplications 1','3.0','o');
insert into course values (5,'cit 102b','pc applications','applications 2','3.0','o');
insert into course values (6,'cit 102c','pc applications','applications 3','3.0','o');
insert into course values (7,'cit 103','computer concepts','introduction systems','3.0','c');
insert into course values (8,'cit 110','Unified language','UML design','3.0','o');
insert into course values (9,'cit 165','cobol','cobol programming','3.0','o');
insert into course values (10,'cit 167','C++ Programming 1','c++ programming','4.0','o');
insert into course values (11,'cit 231','Expert Excel','spreadsheet apps','3.0','o');
insert into course values (12,'cit 233','expert Access','database devel.','3.0','o');
insert into course values (13,'cit 169','Java Programming I','Java Programming I','3.0','o');
insert into course values (14,'cit 263','Visual Basic','Visual Basic Prog','3.0','o');
insert into course values (15,'cit 275','system analysis 2','System Analysis 2','3.0','o');



create table Section(
SectionID       Number(10),
CourseId        Number(10),
SectionNumber   VarChar2(10),
Days        Varchar2(10),
StartTime       Date,
EndTime     Date,
LocationID      Number(10),
SeatAvailable   Number(3),
Status      Char(1));

ALTER TABLE Section
ADD Constraint Section_SectionID_PK PRIMARY KEY(SectionID);


insert into section values (1,1,'18977','r','21-Sep-2011','10-Dec-2011','1','89','o');


create table Location(
LocationId      Number(10),
Building        Varchar2(20),
Room        Varchar2(5),
Capacity        Number(5),
Satus       Char(1));

ALTER TABLE Location
ADD Constraint Location_LocationID_pk PRIMARY KEY (LocationID);

insert into Location values (1,'Clevleand Hall','cl209','35','o');
insert into Location values (2,'Toledo Circle','tc211','45','o');
insert into Location values (3,'Akron Square','as154','65','o');
insert into Location values (4,'Cincy Hall','ch100','45','o');
insert into Location values (5,'Springfield Dome','SD','35','o');
insert into Location values (6,'Dayton Dorm','dd225','25','o');
insert into Location values (7,'Columbus Hall','CB354','15','o');
insert into Location values (8,'Cleveland Hall','cl204','85','o');
insert into Location values (9,'Toledo Circle','tc103','75','o');
insert into Location values (10,'Akron Square','as201','46','o');
insert into Location values (11,'Cincy Hall','ch301','73','o');
insert into Location values (12,'Dayton Dorm','dd245','57','o');
insert into Location values (13,'Springfield Dome','SD','65','o');
insert into Location values (14,'Cleveland Hall','cl241','10','o');
insert into Location values (15,'Toledo Circle','tc211','27','o');
insert into Location values (16,'Akron Square','as311','28','o');
insert into Location values (17,'Cincy Hall','ch415','73','o');
insert into Location values (18,'Toledo Circle','tc111','67','o');
insert into Location values (19,'Springfield Dome','SD','69','o');
insert into Location values (20,'Dayton Dorm','dd211','45','o');

Alter Table Student
Add Constraint student_Zip_CK Check(Rtrim (Zip,'1234567890-') is null);

Alter Table Student
ADD Constraint Student_Status_CK Check(Status In('c','t'));

Alter Table Student
ADD Constraint Student_MI_CK2 Check(RTRIM(MI,'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')is Null);

Alter Table Student
Modify pin not Null;

Alter table Faculty
Add Constraint Faculty_Status_CK Check(Status In('f','a','i'));

Alter table Faculty
ADD Constraint Faculty_Rank_CK Check(Rank In  ('professor','doctor','instructor','assistant','tenure'));

Alter table Faculty
ADD Constraint Faculty_MI_CK2 Check(RTRIM(MI,'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')is Null);

Update Section Set Starttime = To_date('09-21-2011 6:00 PM', 'mm-dd-yyyy hh:mi pm');
Update Section Set Endtime = To_date('12-10-2011 9:50 PM', 'mm-dd-yyyy hh:mi pm');

alter table Section
Add Constraint StartTime_Status_CK Check (starttime < Endtime);

Alter Table Section
Add Constraint Section_StartTime_ck check (StartTime < EndTime);

 Alter Table Section
 ADD Constraint Section_CourseId_FK FOREIGN KEY (CourseID) References Course(CourseId);

 Alter Table Section
 ADD Constraint Section_LocationID_FK FOREIGN KEY (LocationID) References Location (LocationId);

 Alter Table Section
 ADD Constraint Section_Days_CK Check(RTRIM(Days,'mtwrfsu')IS Null);

 update section set seatavailable = '99';

 Alter Table Section
 ADD Constraint Section_SeatsAvailable_CK Check (SeatAvailable < 100);

 Alter Table Course
 Add Constraint Course_CreditHours_ck check(CreditHours < = 6.0);

 update location set capacity = '99'; 

 Alter Table Location
 Add Constraint Location_Capacity_CK Check(Capacity < 100);

 Create Table Registration (
 StudentID      Number(10),
 SectionID      Number(10),
 Constraint Registration_pk Primary key (studentId, Sectionid));

 Insert into registration values (1, 2);
 Insert into Registration values (2, 3);
 Insert into registration values (3, 4);
 Insert into registration values (4, 5);
 Insert into registration values (5, 6);
 Insert into registration values (6, 7);
 Insert into registration values (7, 8);
 Insert into registration values (8, 9);
 insert into registration values (9, 10);
 insert into registration values (10, 11);
 insert into registration values (9, 12);
 insert into registration values (8, 13);
 insert into registration values (7, 14);
 insert into registration values (6, 15);
 insert into registration values (5, 17);
 insert into registration values (4, 18);
 insert into registration values (3, 19);
 insert into registration values (2, 20);
 insert into registration values (1, 21);
 insert into registration values (2, 22);
 insert into registration values (3, 23);
 insert into registration values (4, 24);
 insert into registration values (5, 25);
 Insert into registration values (6, 24);
 insert into registration values (7, 23);
 insert into registration values (8, 22);
 insert into registration values (9, 21);
 insert into registration values (10, 20);
 insert into registration values (9, 19);
 insert into registration values (8, 17);



Create Table courseInstructor(
FacultyID       Number(10),
SectionID       Number(10),
Constraint CourseInstructor_pk Primary key (FacultyId, SectionID));




insert into courseInstructor values (1, 1);
insert into courseInstructor values (2, 2);
insert into courseInstructor values (3, 3);
insert into courseInstructor values (4, 4);
insert into courseInstructor values (5, 5);
insert into courseInstructor values (5, 6);
insert into courseInstructor values (4, 7);
insert into courseInstructor values (3, 8);
insert into courseInstructor values (2, 9);
insert into courseInstructor values (1, 10);
insert into courseInstructor values (5, 11);
insert into courseInstructor values (4, 12);
insert into courseInstructor values (3, 13);
insert into courseInstructor values (2, 14);
insert into courseInstructor values (1, 15);



 Create table grade(
 StudentID      Number(10),
 SectionID      Number(10),
 Grade      Varchar2(1),
 Constraint grade_pk Primary key (StudentID, SectionID));


 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_CreateGrade
 AFTER INSERT ON Registration
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
 INSERT INTO grade (SectionID,StudentID,Grade) 
 VALUES(:New.SectionID,:New.StudentID,NULL);
 END TR_createGrade;
 /

 CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW V_reg_student_course AS
 SELECT 
 Registration.StudentID, 
student.LastName, 
student.FirstName,
course.CourseName,
Registration.SectionID,
course.CreditHours,
section.Days,
TO_CHAR(StartTime, 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS StartDate, 
TO_CHAR(StartTime, 'HH:MI PM') AS StartTime, 
TO_CHAR(EndTime, 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS EndDate,
TO_CHAR(EndTime, 'HH:MI PM') AS EndTime,
location.Building,
location.Room
FROM registration, student, section, course, location
WHERE registration.StudentID = student.StudentID
AND registration.SectionID = section.SectionID
AND section.LocationID = location.LocationID
AND section.CourseID = course.CourseID;

CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW V_teacher_to_course AS
SELECT 
courseInstructor.FacultyID,
faculty.FirstName,
faculty.LastName,
courseInstructor.SectionID,
section.Days,
TO_CHAR(StartTime, 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS StartDate, 
TO_CHAR(StartTime, 'HH:MI PM') AS StartTime, 
TO_CHAR(EndTime, 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS EndDate,
TO_CHAR(EndTime, 'HH:MI PM') AS EndTime,
location.Building,
location.Room
FROM courseInstructor, faculty, section, course, location
WHERE courseInstructor.FacultyID = faculty.FacultyID
AND courseInstructor.SectionID = section.SectionID
AND section.LocationID = location.LocationID
AND section.CourseID = course.CourseID;

SELECT * FROM V_reg_student_course;

SELECT * FROM V_teacher_to_course;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [pl\sql automatiomation of registration table and grade table for a class project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289062/pl-sql-automatiomation-of-registration-table-and-grade-table-for-a-class-project)

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how much detail is required for this exercise but these are the things I see:

You are mixing CHAR and VARCHAR2 types,  there is no reason to do this. Make your life easier and stick with VARCHAR2 if the entries are expected to be less than 4000 characters
Many people's names, cities and addresses are much longer than 20 characters.  Think big, 250 characters.
Middle Initial is problematic. Not everyone has one and if they do they may want their full middle name spelled out.
Address information should be broken out into a series of separate tables but I grant this may be beyond the scope of your assignment
Not everyone lives in the United States, think about a numeric key to a secondary table for cities and states/provinces.
Many of these fields should be not null such as course number, course name

Now, onto your question about automating functions.  I am not sure what you really want. A student registering for a course is initiated outside of the database.  Staff would enter the students registration choices based on a form.  Or the student would submit them electronically,  either way some front-end application would initiate the transaction.

For example, on your front end, someone presses "Submit".  Then the old fashioned way is to open a connection to the database, add some parameters, make a procedure call like

Add_student_to_course(student_id_in IN NUMBER, section_id_in IN NUMBER, registration_out OUT sys_refcursor)
Inside the procedure you check to see whether the student exists, course exists, course has seats available.
There are many different ways of dealing with error handling depending on the complexity of the validation process.  If it is possible for one registration to violate several business rules then you want to return complex information.  (if the course must have a seat available, if the course must have a teacher, if the student is paid up).

So, do your processing as if statements.  When everything is fine, in a simple application, the sys_refcursor could look like
select registration_no, error_number from dual;
If everything is fine error_number is 0, if not return an error code.     Otherwise the registration code is 0 and the error code refers to a table of errors with a human readable text.
(I am aware that this is a simplistic approach but this is a simplified exercise)